# Shortcode content not visible

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have this code that creates a dynamic TOC inside single.php at the top of the page, based on the given class "toc-item" for specific elements. It works as a filter but I would like to use it in a shortcode.

I tried using `add_shortcode('toc_content', 'create_toc');` but it does not display anything. Any idea how can I change this into a shortcode function? Thanks a lot!

```
function create_toc($html) {
  $toc = '';
  if (is_single()) {
      if (!$html) return $html;
      $dom = new DOMDocument();
      
      libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
      $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
      libxml_clear_errors();
      $toc = '<div class="toc-bound">
          <div class="toc-ctr">
              table of contents
          </div>
          <ul class="toc">';
      $h2_status = 0;          
      $i = 1;     

      $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
      $expression = '//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " toc-item ")]';
     
      foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $element) {              
          if($h2_status){
            $toc .= '</li>';
            $h2_status = 0;
          }
          $h2_status = 1;
          $toc .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '#toc-' . $i . '">' . $element->textContent . '</a>';
          $element->setAttribute('id', 'toc-' . $i);
          $i++;          
      }
      
      if($h2_status){
          $toc .= '</li>';
      }
      $toc .= '</ul></div>';
      $html = $dom->saveHTML();
  }
  return $toc . $html;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'create_toc');    
//add_shortcode('toc_content', 'create_toc'); does not work
```

Comment: You can't just use a filter function as a short code function.

Answer (score 0):

The `add_shortcode()` callback function is passed three arguments: `$atts` (an array of shortcode arguments), `$content` (whatever it is inside the shortcode tags, if anything at all) and `$tag` (the name of the shortcode).

Your `$html` argument, as it is, would be an array of shortcode arguments (always empty I'm assuming).
If you just need the shortcode to return a div element, you probably don't need any argument at all. Just return the element.